# MySQL Joining a Table twice

Tags: mysql

I have this Table:

[Table Fluege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm4pk.png)

and I need to Create a VIEW "Umsteigeverbindungen" with the following colums:

[Final Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht1Uo.png)

In the first table I have a list of Flights from different airports. And the task is to create a view that shows all the possible "flight-connections" with only one stopover.
for example:
flying from FRA stoping over in DUB and finally landing in LAX.

That is all I have:
[my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C71ZW.png)

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I would really appreciate if somebody can help me fixing this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Have you done any work yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free pump-and-dump homework service.

Comment: You should also provide the logic that creates the View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUM  does not take two parameters like you did in `sum(fleuge1.Preis,fleuge2.Preis)`

sum is an aggregate function , meant to sum all the values on a column, if you want to sum two values from a two distinct sets just do `fleuge1.Preis+fleuge2.Preis`

if you want to post errors on stack overflow you can just copy them

[image: posted]